# heroku errors ImportError: No module named crispy_forms

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-crispy-forms

I have a question 
When I ran this command  `heroku run python manage.py migrate`

I got this error: `ImportError: No module named crispy_forms`

But on locally every things are doing well but my app is don't to run on Heroku please help me ?

Comment: Is it in your requirements.txt file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also do

```
heroku run pip freeze
```

that will give you a list of installed pip apps on heroku.. but ya also check your requirements.txt file

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when running `heroku run python manage.py migrate` command. Here is what I did and solve the issue:

- Verify the `crispy_forms` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` under `settings.py`
- Run `pip install --upgrade django-crispy-forms` or `pip3 install --upgrade django-crispy-forms` depends on the Python version you are using (pip3 is for Python version 3 and above)

If the aboves didn't work, try Daniel Roseman's suggestion:

- Add this line `django-crispy-forms==1.6.1` (version number will change so verify yourself here https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/CHANGELOG.md) to `requirements.txt` file

This helped me and hope this will work for you as well.  But don't forget to run (i) `git add .`, (ii) `git commit -m "your comment"`, and (iii) `git push heroku master` before running `heroku run python manage.py migrate` command again.

Comment: I am having the same problem as OP, except for `python-decouple`. I have tried steps 2 and 3 as suggested. However, I am wondering whether it is necessary to include `python-decouple` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` of `settings.py`? The README (https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple) doesn't mention it, so how do we determine which modules must be included in `INSTALLED_APPS` and which don't?

Answer (score -1):

if you haven't already, run this on your heroku platform:

```
pip install django-crispy-forms
```

remember that your local dependencies will not be installed automatically on your heroku dynos.

Comment: This won't work at all. `heroku run` starts up a new dyno; django-crispy-forms will be installed there, but not in the actual dyno running your app.

Comment: We need to hear from the OP whether the app is included in requirements.txt.